# How does mongodb 2d index precision influence query performance?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, geospatial, nearsphere

I'm using this query to get objects close to a given location, ordered by distance:

```
{
    "id": { // String
        "$nin": ["<vals>"]
    },
    "date": { // Date
        "$gte": "<val>"
    },
    "location": { // Legacy coordinate pairs
        "$nearSphere": ["<val>"],
        "$maxDistance": "<val>"
    },
    "count": { // Integer
        "$gt": "<val>"
    },
    "param1": { // String
        "$in": ["<vals>"] // 1-10 values
    },
    "param2": { // String
        "$in": ["<vals>"] // 1-10 values
    },
    "param3": { // String
        "$in": ["<vals>"] // 10-100 values
    }
}
```

I tried this index but the query is performing slow (200ms):

```
{
    "location": "2dsphere",
    "count": 1,
    "date": -1,
    "param1": 1
}
```

Location accuracy for the results should be ~ +/- 100m or 0.001 decimal degrees. The location is stored as legacy coordinate pairs.

Would a 2d index with a lower / higher [precision](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/build-a-2d-index/#define-location-precision-for-a-2d-index) increase performance?